# How to find a sentence contains a sequence of specific words in a specific order?

Tags: discussion, support, search

I am trying to find the posts contain sentences like `"*carefully *listen*"`.

1. `*` stands for none or any characters
2. *carefully* has to be put before *listen*
3. *carefully* doesn't need to be next to *listen*
4. *carefully* and *listen* have to be in the same sentence.

so, the following sentences all meet the need

> I carefully listen
>
> I carefully listened
>
> I'm carefully bla bla bla listening while bla bla bla

while each of the following sentences does not meet the need

> listen carefully (wrong order)
>
> carefully. bla bla listen (separate sentences)

I've tried ["carefully listen"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22carefully%20listen%22), ["carefully listen*"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22carefully%20listen*%22), [carefully listen*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=carefully%20listen*), none worked.

How do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that with the on-site search. You need to fallback to the Data Explorer.

I've created this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/1205856?searchfor=carefully+%25listen):

```sql
declare @search nvarchar(max) = ##searchfor:string?carefully %listen##
select id [Post Link]
     , score
     , creationdate
     , lastactivitydate
     , closeddate 
     , owneruserid as [User Link]
from posts
where body like concat('%', @search, '%') collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
or title like concat('%', @search, '%') collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
```

that implements your requirements number 1, 2 and 3. I might be able to get something out with number 4 but I can imagine that is brittle in various ways. It is not easy to determine in SQL what a "sentence" is.

When run today this is the result:

[image: sede result]

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Give a big shout-out to [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio) for the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) she wrote.
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

Answer (score 5):

I don't think the current search engine supports this; it's simply not built to handle these complex cases.

What you *could* do is write a [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) query like [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/1205858). English Language Learners is small enough to do full text searches like this.

```sql
SELECT Id AS [Post Link], CreationDate, Score
  FROM Posts
  WHERE Body LIKE '%carefully%listen%'
    AND Body NOT LIKE '%carefully%.%listen%'
```

This is not fool proof: if you have a sentence containing 'carefully' and 'listen', and *another* sentence containing 'listen' later in the post, it will not be found by this query. Also, sentences may end in question marks, exclamation marks, or users may forget to punctuate altogether.

SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning. Have a look at the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) if you're new to SEDE and/or SQL in general.

Comment: beat me to it by 6 to 8 seconds ...

Comment: You can still beat me because of your superior SQL skills - I always forget what kind of regexes are supported by SQL Server.

Comment: No worries, it is still pretty limited: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15. We're not able to bring SQL to its knees with a catastrophic backtracking trick ...